# Validating forms in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to replace `between:min,max` **min** and **max** using variables containing row values from the table instead of hard coding row the values.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'borrower_id' => 'required',
            'loan_limit' => 'required',
            'loan_amount' => 'required|numeric|between:min,max',
            'interest_rate' => 'required',
            'duration' => 'required',
            'duration_term' => 'required',
        ]);
```

It doesn't show the actual min and max values one should enter in the input field instead it throws an validation error on the input field.

[image: screenshot]

`The loan amount must be between min and max`.

I want it to display the variables containing the minimum and maximum values stored in the database.

Any help guys would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```html
$min_value = //get your min value 
$max_value = //get your max value 

$this->validate($request, [
            'borrower_id' => 'required',
            'loan_limit' => 'required',
            'loan_amount' => 'required|numeric|between:'.$min_value.','.$max_value.',
            'interest_rate' => 'required',
            'duration' => 'required',
            'duration_term' => 'required',
        ]);
```